# asp .net mvc: Populating select option with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm populating a select option using jquery ajax with json data and its working fine, but when I click submit button,  my option value become null. Here's my code:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Teste", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Data Agendamento
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBox("DataAgendamento", null, new { @onchange = "horarios();" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Hora Agendamento
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select id="HoraAgendamento" name="HoraAgendamento"></select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
}
<script>
    function horarios() {
        var Dia = $('#DataAgendamento').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Teste/Popula',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { dia: Dia },
            success: function (horarios) {
                $("#HoraAgendamento").html("");
                $.each(horarios, function (i, hora) {
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(hora.Hora);
                    $("#HoraAgendamento").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(hora.Id).text(hora.Hora));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Controller(until the problem happened)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {

        string dt_data;
        dt_data = form["DataAgendamento"] + " " + form["HoraAgendamento"];
```

The problem is I'm getting form["HoraAgendamento"] as null.

Comment: are you getting the options populated when inspecting using the inspect element in developer tools

Comment: You are using var Dia = $('#DataAgendamento').val(); to get the value. But you didn't assign the id of the textbox.@Html.TextBox("name", new { id = "name"}, new { @class = "text-field" })

Comment: @KateFernando the id and name will be assigned by mvc framework that's not the concern here

Comment: @Krishna, Thanks... Thats right.

Comment: @Rodney, do you have any values in the select list?

Comment: @Saravanan yes, I getting them populated.

Comment: @kateFernando, no until I change the DataAgendamento field, then select options are populated.

Comment: How is your dropdown getting populated? I checked the code and <select id="dropdowntipo" name="dropdowntipo">
                <option value="Exemplo1">Exemplo1</option>
                <option value="Exemplo2">Exemplo2</option>
                <option value="Exemplo3">Exemplo3</option>
            </select> works for me if I use form["dropdowntipo"] to access it.

Comment: @KateFernando, I don't know with I understand your question. My dropdown is getting populated by Ajax. You can check in my View. And it's working very well, as I commented before, I also checked in developer tools and the result looks like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an odd solution but it's working now.

I have just replaced hora.Id by hora.Hora in my JavaScript as bellow

Old one:

```
$('<option></option>').val(hora.Id).text(hora.Hora));
```

New one:

```
$('<option></option>').val(hora.Hora).text(hora.Hora));
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

try with code

```
string dt_data = Request.Form["DataAgendamento"].ToString() + " " + Request.Form["HoraAgendamento"].ToString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you would get that value as null. I tried doing exactly what you are doing here, and I could get that value perfectly. Please see below for what I did:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function horarios() { 

    var Dia = $('#DataAgendamento').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Popula")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { dia: Dia },
        success: function (horarios) {

            $("#HoraAgendamento").html("");
            $.each(horarios, function (i, hora) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(hora.Hora);
                $("#HoraAgendamento").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(hora.Id).text(hora.Hora));
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index1", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            Data Agendamento
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBox("DataAgendamento", null, new { @onchange = "horarios();" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            Hora Agendamento
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select id="HoraAgendamento" name="HoraAgendamento"></select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
    public JsonResult Popula(string dia)
    {
        var obj = new { Id = 1, Hora = "Drop down" };
        var obj1 = new { Id = 2, Hora = "Drop down 2" };
        List<Object> ob = new List<object>();
        ob.Add(obj);
        ob.Add(obj1);
        return Json(ob, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Index1(FormCollection form)
    {
        string dt_data;
        dt_data = form["DataAgendamento"] + " " + form["HoraAgendamento"];

        return View();
    }
```

And the result:

[image]

My recommendation would be to check if the value of Id is correctly passed from `Popula()`.